How can I fix "CVE-2023-42364 busybox/busybox Use After Free" vulnerability in node:alpine for Next.js application?
I have the following Dockerfile for my Next.js application:
FROM node:alpine AS base

# 2) Install dependencies only when needed.
FROM base AS deps

# 3) Install packages with no cache
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

# 4) Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm update && npm install


# 5) Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# 6) Build the code
RUN npm run build

# 7) Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# 8) Set the correct permission for prerender cache.
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# 9) Reduce the Image size
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

# 10) Expose the port
USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# 11) server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]

Snyk gives me the following vulnerability:

busybox/busybox Use After Free
Medium vulnerability
https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-ALPINE320-BUSYBOX-7233533

The fix is to "Upgrade Alpine:3.20 busybox to version 1.36.1-r29 or higher.", but I am using the latest node:alphine, without specifying a version in my Dockerfile?
How can I fix this vulnerability?

If I do docker run --rm -ti node:alpine apk info --no-cache busybox, I do get the fact that the busybox package is at the version busybox-1.36.1-r29. Are you sure you really have the latest of node:alpine in your local registry? >> docker pull node:alpine

You can also do docker run --pull always --rm -ti node:alpine apk info --no-cache busybox, in this case, to test.
